# find a subsequence relatively prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n := n^2 + 2$.

1. Find a subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_{n_i}$ and $a_{n_j}$ are relatively prime whenever $i \neq j$.
2. And another subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_{n_i}\mid a_{n_j}$ whenever $i \lt j$.

[My attempt so far. I cannot continue with the remainder theorem because $(a_{n_i})$ & $(a_{n_j})$ are not integers. I don't even know if I have the mathematical technicality to complete such a problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyzPx.png)

Comment: What do you/they/"it" mean by **find**? Simply prove that such subsequences exist? Give a constructive way to build them? Or "find" them in closed form?

Comment: I'd try to do the first one recursively. Start with $a_1=3$.  Let $a_2=a_1^2+2=11$, then let $a_n=(\prod a_i)^2+2$, something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for the second one, let $x_1 = 1$, and $x_{m+1} = x_m^2 + x_m+2$. Now, we note that:
$$a_{x_{m+1}} = x_{m+1}^2 + 2 = (x_m^2+2x_m+3)(x_m^2 + 2) $$

is a multiple of $a_{x_m}$. By induction, this gives a sequence of numbers, each of whom is a multiple of the previous number and therefore of all numbers before it.

this gives the sequence $x_i : 1,4,22,508...$ with $a_i : 3,18,486,258066 $, each of which is a multiple of the number before it.

---

For the first question, note that if $m=k(n^2+2)$ for any positive odd integer $k$, then $p$ divides $m^2+2$ and $p$ divides $n^2+2$ implies that $p$ divides $2$, and if $n$ is odd, then $m$ is odd, so this forces $p=1$, and hence $m^2+2$ and $n^2+2$ are coprime.

To create the desired sequence, then we let $x_1 = 1$ and ensure that $x_{m}$ is a odd multiple of $x_1^2 +2,x_2^2+2,...,x_{m-1}^2+2$, so that $a_{x_m}, a_{x_n}$ would be co prime since (WLOG $m > n$) we would have $x_m$ as an odd multiple of $x_n$, so by our argument $a_{x_m},a_{x_n}$ would be co prime.

For example, we may take $x_1 = 1$, and $x_{m} = \prod_{j=1}^{m-1} (x_{j}^2+2)$. Then the resulting sequence $a_{x_n}$ has pairwise co prime numbers.

For example, this sequence results in $x_1=1,x_2 = 3,x_3 = 11 \times 3 = 33, x_4 = 11 \times 3 \times 35 = 1155$,  and so on. Check that $a_{x_n}$ looks like $3,11,1091,1334027,...$